# Why is there no accurate C++ decompiler?

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, decompiler

Why is it not possible to create a C++ decompiler that will function as accurately as those made for Java and C#?

Comment: A very good question. After investigating and understanding how C++ gets compiled down to machine code, and how Java works, you should be able to have a pretty good idea as to the reasons why.

Comment: I think the main reason is that c++ doesn't provide any runtime reflection mechanisms.

Comment: After all we've seen, how is this Q&A still not a duplicate?

Comment: Nobody wants to put in the time and effort required to make one

Comment: The JVM bytecode is a lot closer to the source language that machine code to C++ source code. There are many constructs in C++ that will compile to the same object code. This is much less true of Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several reasons:

1. Inlining. A lot of C++ code gets inlined in optimized builds. That plays havoc with any form of decompiler. To figure out that a function was inlined, the decompiler would have to analyze the specifics of the inlined code and match them up. And post-inlining optimization steps can make code very different, depending on where it was inlined.
2. Templates. Templates use #1 exclusively, but they create additional problems. It is at least theoretically possible that a function that gets inlined in two places would compile to the same sequence of assembly instructions. But for template code, which was instantiated with different template arguments? Different instantiations will usually have to compile down to different sequences of instructions. And this becomes even more difficult, since template code can call different sets of functions based on the template parameters. And those functions themselves could be inlined.
3. Compile-time execution. Template metaprogramming allows the compiler to actually execute code. But C++11's `constexpr` provides a more natural way to do some computations at compile time. Obviously, compile-time function calls or metafunction instantiations *cannot* be part of the compiled executable. Only the results of them will be (since that's kinda the point).
4. Lack of comprehensive runtime reflection. C# and Java both lace their bytecode with a lot of information about what the nature of the original source code. Object definitions are easily detectable, as are object names, member variable types and names, etc. C++ compiles down to machine language, which is not required to have any such information. And since it isn't required, compilers don't generate it. Even the reflection study group of the ISO C++ committee is focused on *compile-time* reflection, which is information that won't be available at runtime.

   Even `std::type_info` doesn't offer anything. The reason being that, if the compiler does not detect that a particular type will have `typeid` called on it, then the compiler doesn't need to generate a `std::type_info` object for it. And even if it did, all that gives you is an object's name (and an identifier). Nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

Because C++ compilers generally do not put any more information into the executable than they absolutely have to (especially not if they are compiling in release mode rather than a debug build), so the information you'd need to accurately decompile the program simply is not present in the executable.

Of course a C++ compiler could be made that does include all of the necessary information in the executable (e.g. in the most naive implementation, it could simply include a copy of the source code itself in the executable), but doing so would make the executables significantly larger, and most non-open-source C++ developers would prefer that other people *not* be able to decompile the executable, so there isn't a whole lot of demand for that functionality.